# How else to ensure the order of a @ManyToMany List?

Tags: jpa, jpa-2.0, eclipselink

Consider:

```
@Entity
public class M {

    @ManyToMany
    private List<E> es = new ArrayList<E>();
    private E newE;

    public M(E newE) {
        this.newE = newE;
        es.add(newE);
    }
```

Cannot I `assert(m.newE == m.getEs(0))`?

I could only if after rebooting the app/PU is:

```
  public List<E> getEs() {
    final int indexOf = es.indexOf(newE);
    if (indexOf != 0) {
        es.remove(indexOf);
        es.add(0, newE);
    }
    return Collections.unmodifiableList(es);
}
```

However this burdensome code is even inefficient as it forces loading the E entitities from the PU before they may actually be needed. Any alternative that works?

Answer (score 0):

> Cannot I `assert(m.newE == m.getEs(0))`?

**No**, if there are any objects in the `@ManyToMany`, `newE` will be added at the end of the list. Also, I believe the list will be lazy-loaded before the insert, so your concern about things being inefficient doesn't really apply.

If you're only concerned about the ordering of elements when loaded from the persistence unit, [@OrderBy](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/OrderBy.html) will do the trick.

```
@ManyToMany
@Orderby("someproperty ASC")
private List<E> es = new ArrayList<E>();
```

If you also want to maintain order at runtime while adding elements, you'll have to implement [compareTo()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html) or a separate [Comparator](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html), then use [Collections.sort()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort%28java.util.List,%20java.util.Comparator%29), or use a naturally sorted collection like [SortedSet](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/SortedSet.html).

Answer (score 0):

`JPA` also provides an `@OrderColumn` if you want the order maintained.

[See this link](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/Relationships#Ordering)

Otherwise changes to the order of the elements of the list are not considered a persistent change.